# App.config in WPF Progam, works during Debug but not compiled

Tags: c#, wpf, web-services

I have a WPF Program that uses a Soap service that is generated by Visual Studio.

When I run it in debug mode in Visual Studio it works fine (I put the contracts in app.config)

but when I run it after it is compiled, with the App.config in the directory where my progam is i get this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find endpoint element with name 'LodgeSoap' and 
contract 'SMSwebService.LodgeSoap' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might
be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element
matching this name could be found in the client element.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you compile the application, it would have the assemblies in either the bin/debug or the bin/release directory. Please make sure that there is a [application name].exe.config file is present in the folder and the soap service configuration information is present in this file.